# The property SplashForm is not a valid search property

Tags: c#, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I trying to create simple test that runs my application and clicks some button using `CodedUI`.
First I trying to find the main window, that has ControlName - "LoginForm". This is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod()
{
    var app = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\application.exe");
    var loginWindow = new WinClient(app);
    loginWindow.SearchProperties.Add(loginWindow.ControlName, "LoginForm");
```

When I run it in debugger, the `loginWindow` object contains an error:

```
The property SplashForm is not a valid search property.
```

[image: Screenshot]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Redo your `SearchProperties` line like this:

```
loginWindow.SearchProperties[WinClient.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "LoginForm";
```